# VSCode Integrated Terminal and Git for Windows (git-bash) absolute paths to file

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash, git-for-windows

In the past, I remember VS Codium being able to open Git for Windows path (using git bash) but now, whenever I have a shell script outputting an absolute path:

- VSCode detect the path if I try Ctrl + Click
- The path is not interpreted correctly.

If for example I try:

```
$ realpath /c/ProgramData/Docker
/c/ProgramData/Docker
```

And Click + Hover on `/c/ProgramData/Docker` then VSCode asks me to open `\c\ProgramData\Docker` and fails (because that's not a valid windows path, whereas `C:\ProgramData\Docker` is).

Is there a setting or an extension I did miss ?

Comment: why does the DocLinkProvider on windows accept the path `/c/ProgramData/Docker`, it is not a valid windows path

Comment: The path is _valid_ for git bash, eg: git bash represent Windows path as POSIX path: internally, it convert `/c/ProgramData/Docker` into `C:\ProgramData\Docker` (like if `cygpath -w /c/ProgramData/Docker` was called).  As for DocLinkProvider, is that the stuff that detect and try to open links from terminals?

Comment: DocLinkProvider is the routine called by VSC written in an extension that registers it can detect Ctrl+Click links is the language of the current editor/terminal

Comment: Is there a way to determine which one is responsible for the link I try to access?